# Implementing sequence : List<Observable<T>> -> Observable<List<T>>

Tags: functional-programming, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

For every type T,
having a list of n Observables of Ts, I'd like to build an Observable emitting a list of n Ts each time one of the original Observables emits something.
This is often refereed as the 'sequence' operator in the functional literature.

Desired behaviour example in a pseudo-syntax:

```
val o1 = BehaviourSubject.create(true)
val o2 = BehaviourSubject.create(false)
val listOfObservables = [o1,o2]

val observableOfList = sequence(listOfObservables)

observableOfList.subscribe(print)

o2.onNext(true)

// Expected output:
// [true, false]
// [true, true]
```

I wrote the following naive implementation in java, which misbehave:

```
public static <T> Observable<List<T>> sequence(List<Observable<T>> from) {
  return fold(from, Observable.<List<T>>never().startWith(new ArrayList<T>()),
            (arrayListObservable, observable) -> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(arrayListObservable, observable, (ts, t) -> {
      ts.add(t);
      return ts;
    });
  });
}

public static <F, T> T fold(final Iterable<? extends F> elements, final T zero, final Func2<T, F, T> f) {
  T currentValue = zero;
  for (final F element : elements) {
    currentValue = f.call(currentValue, element);
  }
  return currentValue;
}

// Actual output
// [true, false]
// [true, false, true]
```

Somehow I need to rebuild the resulting list instead of appendiong the new values to the existing one. How would you guys/ladies go with it ?

Thanks for you time and future answers !

Answer (score 2):

[Rxx](http://rxx.codeplex.com/) has an overload of `CombineLatest` which takes a collection of observables and does exactly what you want.  You should be able to port the source code for that method over to Java fairly easily.

Comment: Hi Brandon, Thanks for your answer that lead me to re-evaluate deeply rxjava doc. And you know what? Recent 0.18.x versions do provide an array-taking CombineLatest!
Here is how I used it to achieve a 
sequence :: List<Observable<T>> -> -> Observable<List<T>> equivalent: